# Injecting RoleManager results in error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

First things first, my issue is similar to this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34131432/1019042), but not the same

I am going through the Identity sample from microsoft. I started it with only user authentication and it worked. I removed the DB because I want to use Database first. Now I am trying to incorporate Roles.

My setup is like this for user (works without role) and role (didn't work):

My DB entities are setup as such:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(e =>
        {
            e.ToTable("User").HasKey(x => x.Id);
            e.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        });

        builder.Entity<IdentityRole<int>>(e =>
        {
            e.ToTable("Role").HasKey(x => x.Id);
            e.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("RoleId");
        });
```

and my context, user setup (I want to keep using the original IdentityRole)

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
}
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
}
```

in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

in AccountController, I tried this:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly ISmsSender _smsSender;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ISmsSender smsSender,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _smsSender = smsSender;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AccountController>();
    }
```

The app still load on the browser and it remembers that I've logged in before but when I try to logout for example, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[MyProj.Web.Models.MyViewModels.ApplicationRole]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'MyProj.Web.Controllers.AccountController'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` by `RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>>` and it should work.

Comment: I had tried that earlier but with the wrong configuration and remained in mind that I've tried that and it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the exception message seems to imply you're using `MyProj.Web.Models.MyViewModels.ApplicationRole`. If that's true, make sure you're not also using `IdentityRole` somewhere in your code.